# Proof that $h = g \circ f^{-1}$ is $(\overline{\mathcal{B}}, \overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions, borel-measures

I am studying for measure theory. Now there is this one question which I am trying to proof, and I think I am on to something. However, there is one part which I can't get my head over, which would help me a lot with my proof.

So we have 3 functions; $g$, $f$ and $h$. We know that $g, f: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, which are both $(\sigma(f), \overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable.

Here $$\sigma(f) = \bigcap_{\substack{\mathcal{A}: \mathcal{A} \text{ is a $\sigma$-algebra}\\\text{of sets of $\Omega$ and $f$ is}\\ \text{$(\mathcal{A},\overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable}}}\mathcal{A}.$$

Now I have $h = g \circ f^{-1}$. How do I prove that $h$ is $(\overline{\mathcal{B}}, \overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable?

I have already tried several things, but none which seem to work out. Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is $f^{-1}$ in this context?

Comment: @drhab just any function from $\Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ that is $(\sigma(f), \overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable.

Comment: But if $f^{-1}$ has codomain $\overline{\mathbb R}$ then $g\circ f^{-1}$ is not properly defined because $g$ has domain $\Omega$.

Comment: That should be okay right? then $h: \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: No, because $h$ as defined should have the same domain as $f^{-1}$ which - as you said in your first comment - is $\Omega$.

Comment: I don't think I am understanding you properly. If $f: \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, then $f^{-1} : \overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \Omega.$ Right?

Comment: An inverse $f^{-1}$ only exists if $f$ is bijective. Is it? Then it should at least be mentioned in your question.That's why I asked in my first comment what $f^{-1}$ is.

Comment: Yeah. Good point. However, we know that $f$ is measurable, hence its inverse should exist by definition of it being measurable.

Comment: That is definitely not the case. Are you perhaps confusing inverses of functions (notation $f^{-1}$) with preimages under $f$ (notations like $f^{-1}(B)$)? There are lots of measurable functions that have no inverse.

Comment: So the fact that $f$ is $(\sigma(f), \overline{\mathcal{B}})$-measurable, which means that $f^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(f) \forall B\in \overline{\mathcal{B}}$ does not imply that $f$ has an inverse? So what is the difference between $f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}$?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is (if it exists, and in most cases it does not) a function. If $f:X\to Y$ is a function then for every subset $B\subseteq Y$ we have the preimage of $B$ with respect to function $f$. It is a subset of $X$ and is defined as:$$f^{-1}(B):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in B\}$$For this to be properly defined no conditions on $f$ are necessary. The function $f$ is measurable if for every measurable subset $B$ of $Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(B)$ is a measurable subset of $X$.

Comment: Aha. okay. you are right. thanks a lot.